# Cocos2d : crash with KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS in CoreFoundation

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I got a crash in my app with the following crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: 16EF7339-4E8F-4083-9E63-9404BC0A5A3A
CrashReporter Key:   174928c573ccbe3e1a44d9bd43a33374a9833ab5
Hardware Model:      iPad3,1
Process:         Killer [2930]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/81EFF1B0-3DE0-4874-B7AA-0ACA60CBB3C2/Killer.app/Killer
Identifier:      Killer
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-01-15 20:05:27.000 +0100
OS Version:      iOS 6.0.1 (10A523)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x41d58a76
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32e8e564 _cache_getImp + 4
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32e8ef84 lookUpMethod + 24
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32e901d2 class_respondsToSelector + 26
3   CoreFoundation                  0x38bac600 objectIsKindOfClass + 32
4   CoreFoundation                  0x38bac358 __handleUncaughtException + 64
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32e93a62 _ZL15_objc_terminatev + 126
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33844078 _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33844110 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33845594 __cxa_rethrow + 84
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32e939cc objc_exception_rethrow + 8
10  CoreFoundation                  0x38af2f1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
11  CoreFoundation                  0x38af2d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
12  GraphicsServices                0x370a32e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
13  UIKit                           0x3a2c02f4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
14  Killer                          0x00063e38 main (main.m:14)
15  Killer                          0x000622bc start + 36
```

I really have no idea about how to debug this. Should i suspect a crash in a library called by my app ? Am i responsible for this crash, where to look at then ?
Of course the line 14 in Killer main is:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
```

thank you very much guys

Comment: Which code, i don't know where it crashes... The main is the standard Cocos2d main.

Comment: Ok fine, but that was not written in the question.

Comment: @Max did you make any progress ?

Comment: @Jules : not really, please see my comment all the way down this page

Answer (score 1):

The crash log gives very little information. Anyway, I am puzzled by that:

```
objc_exception_rethrow
__cxa_rethrow
```

so it seems that there is some C++ exception handling going on. (Specifically, while handling an exception, another exception is thrown. This will cause terminate to be executed).

This might give you a hint. Are you using any C++ library?

You could also try and set `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` but I suspect you are not able to reproduce the issue...

(Of course, it could well be some iOS SDK framework written in C++ to cause the exception, but just to check)...

Comment: CocosDenshion (cocos2d sound engine) throws C++ exceptions quite often at startup, it might be that.

Comment: Thank you all for your hints, your are totally right, i am not able to reproduce this issue, but it occurs sometimes... I normally do not have extra c++ libs, apart from what the standard cocos2d template project needs. I use the sound engine because i have background music and FX sounds. Is there a way to track it ?

Comment: what do you mean by tracking? you could modify CocosDenshion and wrap all public methods body in a try/catch block; but not being able to reproduce the crash is a major complication since you cannot verify if that fixes it...

Comment: I meant : is there a way to see correctly what i am doing wrong in the next stack of crash dump ? I suppose the CocosDenshion lib is more stable than my proper app, so how could it give a periodic crash like this ?... thank you

Comment: I am wonder whether this crash could be linked to my wrong memory management in my app. I've just realize that i receive     didReceiveMemoryWarning quite often. Where i make a purge of all cached cctextures. If some textures are members of my current scene, and are used, i'll probably have a crash...

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS may be related to accessing some memory which has been already freed. the fact is, if you are receiving memory warnings (which is utterly normal) and you are not crashing, chances are you are doing it right. on the other hand this really seems related to some C++ code, which rules out textures. what about the state of your CocosDenshion objects?

Comment: @sergio : what do you mean by "the state of your cocosdenshion objects" ? I am just playing a background music all the time (starting in the intro ccscene), and playing some FX sounds all along the game. I've reduced size of all my sounds by going from stereo to mono and from 44Khz sampling to 22khz, and saving as 92kbps mp3 instead of 128kbps. I haven't had the same issue since then... But i cannot say the crash is really gone... a bit frightenning because i am now delivering my app to Apple :)

Comment: by cocosdenshion state I mean if they are deleted, e.g. In any case, keep in mind that while background music is played by loading it into memory chunk by chunk, effect files are loaded entirely. this could increase memory usage, make some music data be deallocated, hence the crash. I have just pushed to my github account a category I wrote to play effects chunk by chunk: https://github.com/sdesimone/iOSSnippets/tree/master/cocos2D/SimpleAudioEngine%2BForegroundMusic -- don't know if it can help.

Comment: very interesting sergio, in fact i was wonderig all the time, how to dealloc sound effects correctly, but didn't find anything like this. I am going to look at your example closely. The crash occur again today with the following backtrace : 
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x81f089b2
Crashed Thread:  0
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x3b639564 _cache_getImp + 4
1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x3b639f84 lookUpMethod + 24
2   libobjc.A.dylib                0x3b63b1d

Comment: Do you think this could be linked to this : http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/35023 ?

Comment: I am not sure, since I don't know if you are doing the same. In any case, setting delegates to nil in dealloc methods is very good practice, so I would give it a try...